# Can't find CssSelector with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do some automated tests with Selenium, but I have a problem. I want to be able to press a special button, but this button does not have an `ID` or `Class`, which is the first thing I try to look for.

I Think that I need to use the `CssSelector`, but how exactly should I write to find the correct button in my test?

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(??))
```

[image]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Share selectors that you've tried already along with exception/current output

Comment: Thanks. I will make my future posts better then this one. This was my first post and I was obiously too fast with creating it.

Comment: I have not tried any Before since this was something completely new and I did not know how to work with it. But since I got some nice answers in this thread that worked I now see how you should Think when using it :)

Comment: The feedback you were given was so you would fix *THIS* post... *AND* all future posts. Please edit this post and fix the issues based on feedback given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sibling `<table>` `id` as starting point

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#tbl_bestallningslita ~ button"));
```

Or use the `onclick` attribute (partial)

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[onclick*='btn_taBort']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of the below CSSLocators should help:

`button[accessKey="T"]`

OR

`button[onclick="folkbokforing_form.btn_taBort.click()"]`

Comment: They did! Thanks! :)

Comment: I could just accept one answer apparently. Both you and the guy Before gave good answers, but i had to pick one.

Comment: @HannesHaag, ok.Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath too, xpath gives you more flexibility over cssselector although its quite slower than cssselector.

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("*//button[@onclick='folkbokforging_form.btn.taBort.click()']"));
```

or use combined two attributed xpath,

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("*//button[@accesskey='T' and contains(@onlcinck,'btn_taBort.click()')]");
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not used with the XPath yet (I am very new to Selenium). But I will look it up and learn more about it!